# Expected ')' compilation error pointing at line using a macro

Tags: objective-c, macros, compiler-errors

I am getting a compilation error, and no amount of Googling or attempting to solve it seems to work.

I can show it by example:

```
#import "test.h"

#define FOO 6;
@implementation test

-(void)test {

    for (int i; i< FOO; i++) {    // Error: Expected ')'

        NSLog(@"test1");

    }

    if (1 < FOO) {
        NSLog(@"test2");
    }

}

@end
```

In the `-test` method, it always gives an error where `FOO` is.

This is in Xcode 5.0.2 with default settings/setup.

I've tried Product>Clean, Product>Build. Tried putting the defines in the header. Tried putting them above any code (above the `#import`). Here is a screenshot:

[image: http://imgur.com/OZPTTIg]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need semicolon after `#define`

i.e.

```
#define FOO 6
```

otherwise your code translated to

```
for (int i; i< 6;; i++) {
```

and hence the syntax error